# And Or R function

Tags: r

Is there a way to add an OR into the below function?

```
AA20 = MSRB[which(MSRB$ParTraded <=100 & MSRB$Year == 2020 & MSRB$AverageRating == "AA",]
```

I am looking to instead of having == "AA", make it read as OR "AA", "AA+", "AA-".

Comment: Are you looking for `%in%`? e.g. `MSRB$AverageRating %in% c("AA", "AA+", "AA-")`

Comment: Or use `grepl("^AA[+-]?$", MSRB$AverageRating)`

Comment: I am trying to filter the data first by ParTraded, Year, and then any of three AverageRating (AA, AA+, AA-)

Comment: Annoying solution: `x == A & y == B & (z == C | z == D | z == E)`. Nice option, suggestion from the first comment, `x == A & y == B & z %in% c(C, D, E)`.

Answer (score 2):

This will give you the desired result:

```
AA20 = MSRB[which(MSRB$ParTraded <=100 & MSRB$Year == 2020 & MSRB$AverageRating %in% c("AA", "AA-", "AA+")),]
```

This will filter the rows of the data by ParTraded, Year and when AverageRating is "AA", "AA-" or "AA+"

note that `which` is not needed since the rows will be filtered based on which ones are TRUE:

```
AA20 = MSRB[MSRB$ParTraded <=100 & MSRB$Year == 2020 & MSRB$AverageRating %in% c("AA", "AA-", "AA+"),]
```

Another way to do it is using the 'or' operator `|`:

```
AA20 = MSRB[MSRB$ParTraded <=100 & MSRB$Year == 2020 & (MSRB$AverageRating == "AA" | MSRB$AverageRating == "AA-" | MSRB$AverageRating == "AA+"),]
```

#### Edit

A way to simplify by only having to write MSRB once by using `with`. Suggested by @Gregor:

```
AA20 = MSRB[with(MSRB, ParTraded <=100 & Year == 2020 & (AverageRating == "AA" | AverageRating == "AA-" | AverageRating == "AA+")),]
```

Comment: @BrianSteeves does this answer your question? If not, I can see what I can do to change my answer. If it does, could you accept the answer as the correct answer? Thanks!

Comment: @brian-steeves does this answer your question? If not, I can see what I can do to change my answer. If it does, could you accept the answer as the correct answer? Thanks!